# database migration in Yii

Tags: php, mysql, yii, database-migration

In order to doing [migration in Yii](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CDbSchema#getColumnType-detail) I used this lines

```
<?php

class m110714_122129_users extends CDbMigration
{
  public function up()
  {
        $this-> createTable('{{users}}',array(
   'id' => 'pk',
   'username' => 'VARCHAR (80) NOT NULL',
   'password' => 'VARCHAR (80) NOT NULL',
   'email' => 'VARCHAR (128) NOT NULL',
   'activekey' => 'VARCHAR (128) NOT NULL DEFAULT \'\'',
   'createtime' => 'INTEGER (10) NOT NULL DEFAULT \'0\' ',
   'lastvisit' => 'INTEGER (10) NOT NULL DEFAULT \'0\' ',
   'superuser' => 'INTEGER (1) NOT NULL DEFAULT \'0\' ',
    'status'=> 'INTEGER (1) NOT NULL DEFAULT \'0\' ',
));

  }

  public function down()
  {
    echo "m110714_122129_users does not support migration down.\n";
    return false;
  }

  /*
  // Use safeUp/safeDown to do migration with transaction
  public function safeUp()
  {
  }

  public function safeDown()
  {
  }
  */
}
```

To get

```
 CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `nt_users` (
      `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
      `username` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
      `password` varchar(128) NOT NULL,
      `email` varchar(128) NOT NULL,
      `activkey` varchar(128) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
      `createtime` int(10) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
      `lastvisit` int(10) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
      `superuser` int(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
      `status` int(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    );
```

But now I want to make some changes like doing unique key

```
UNIQUE KEY `username` (`username`),
  UNIQUE KEY `email` (`email`),
  KEY `status` (`status`),
  KEY `superuser` (`superuser`)
```

so how to make that? I searched Yii documentation but not found any thing. So any help will be highly appreciated..

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Just supply them as non-associative values in the array like this:

```
$this-> createTable('{{users}}',array(
   'id' => 'pk',
   'username' => 'VARCHAR (80) NOT NULL',
   'password' => 'VARCHAR (80) NOT NULL',
   'email' => 'VARCHAR (128) NOT NULL',
   'activekey' => 'VARCHAR (128) NOT NULL DEFAULT \'\'',
   'createtime' => 'INTEGER (10) NOT NULL DEFAULT \'0\' ',
   'lastvisit' => 'INTEGER (10) NOT NULL DEFAULT \'0\' ',
   'superuser' => 'INTEGER (1) NOT NULL DEFAULT \'0\' ',
   'status'=> 'INTEGER (1) NOT NULL DEFAULT \'0\' ',
   'UNIQUE KEY `username` (`username`)',
   'UNIQUE KEY `email` (`email`)',
   'KEY `status` (`status`)',
   'KEY `superuser` (`superuser`)',
));
```

This way they will be added to the end of the create statement without any change.

Answer (score 12):

```
$this->createTable('{{users}}',
    array(
        'id' => 'pk',
        'username' => 'varchar(80) NOT NULL',
        'password' => 'varchar(80) NOT NULL',
        'email' => 'varchar(128) NOT NULL',
        'activkey' => 'varchar(128) NOT NULL DEFAULT \'\'',
        'createtime' => 'integer(10) NOT NULL DEFAULT \'0\'',
        'lastvisit' => 'integer(10) NOT NULL DEFAULT \'0\'',
        'superuser' => 'integer(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT \'0\'',
        'status' => 'integer(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT \'0\'',
    ),
);

$this->createIndex('username', '{{user}}', 'username', true);
$this->createIndex('email', '{{user}}', 'email', true);
$this->createIndex('superuser', '{{user}}', 'superuser', false);
$this->createIndex('status', '{{user}}', 'status', false);
```

See http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CDbMigration#createIndex-detail for more details.