# Yii migration addColumn - add explaining comment

Tags: php, mysql, yii, migration

I've no problems with migrations in Yii. 
But one things bothers me a lot.

I can't manage to add comment to it.

```
    public function safeUp()
    {
       $this->addColumn('product_supplier', 'type_search', "'INT(1) DEFAULT \'0\'' COMMENT  'field hohohoho'  ");
    }
```

In phpmyadmin I used to add comments in such way:

[image]

This feature helps a lot to support project.

I would like to be able to do comments in migrations.

Everything what I found is [this post](http://www.yiiframework.com/forum/index.php/topic/48668-yii-migration-example-with-safe-up/):

[image]

But I need to add comment in addColumn function. Because I already have the table. Recreating it is not a option because I would lose all data in it.

Maybe someone can guess the proper syntax?

Thanks.

Comment: gosh, I would rather prefer to get a tip and be downvoted rather than have fields without comments

Comment: Some titme I had similar problem. I solved it by execute query which just adds comment. Dunno how to do it in mysql (I works on postgres) but look at http://cornempire.net/2010/04/15/add-comments-to-column-mysql/

Comment: TIP: post code rather than image of code. In this way it can be searched and copied to test solutions.

Comment: Why do you have single quotes here : 'INT(1) DEFAULT \'0\' ' ?

Comment: I took an example from here - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6693134/database-migration-in-yii . Link for screenshoted code is provided above it.

Comment: He he not to nitpick @Tebe but SO similarly dislikes links. Because often, sites disappear, leaving just a dead link that's not helpful. The best way to include a code fragment in your post is by copy-pasting the code and placing it in a code sample block (see the helpful button with the `{}` icon). You should still add the link to the original post where you copied from, because SO is also big on attribution. Credit where credit is due.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, it was pretty straightforward:

```
        $this->createTable('order',[

       'user_margin_user_id' =>  'INT(32) DEFAULT \'0\'  COMMENT "EXPLAINING COMMENT"',    

    ], 'ENGINE=InnoDB CHARSET=utf8');
```

Comment: You should consider accepting [Yasar Arafath's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41422837/286685) instead. Because when you cram the comment in the type information as you do here, Yii2 basically gives up trying to understand the type and just copies it literally to the SQL, which means it might not work on all database types. Yasser's answer is using the special method `addCommentOnColumn`, which Yii2 does understand and thus will work on all supported databases.

Answer (score 4):

In yii2 format

- addCommentOnColumn($table, $column, $comment)
- dropCommentFromColumn($table, $column)
- addCommentOnTable($table, $comment)
- dropCommentFromTable($table)

Example:
    In migration file

```
$this->addCommentOnColumn('user','role_id','Relation table of role');
```

Comment: just a syntatical sugar

Comment: This should be the accepted answer imho.